# WebApi 2 with OWIN - Authorization Challenge does not redirect to Log In

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin, openid-connect

I'm trying to leverage OWIN with OpenIdConnect Authentication to log into Azure Active Directory.  My application is ASP .NET using WebApi 2.  The front end is just simple HTML/Javascript at this point.  When running my application locally I call a WebApi on a controller (neither the controller nor any API's have the [Authorize] filter) and that API in turn uses the current OWIN Context to challenge authentication.  This challenge fails as expected because I'm not logged in and proceeds to call "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=..." which is also expected.  The request comes back with a 200 status and the response contains the HTML for the Microsoft Log In page.  However my web application does not redirect to that log in page and the console displays a CORS error:

> Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[removed]&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a20776%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access+User.Read+Mail.Send+Files.ReadWrite&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties[removed]:
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:20776' is therefore not allowed access.

I forced my way past the CORS issue with a browser extension but even then it did not redirect to the sign page.  Instead the response contained the source for the sign in page as before.  I've outlined the steps I've taken and the code I'm using below.  Am I missing a step?

Most of the documentation and examples I have found leverage ASP.NET MVC.  I've based much of the implementation off of an MVC example found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

That example runs just fine locally and I'm able to log in with my AAD credentials and successfully call the MS Graph API's.

As for the CORS issue I do not see this in the MVC example.  Why is this CORS issue manifesting in my current setup and how do I get around it?  I expected the OWIN middleware to take care of this.  Using the EnableCors filter on the controller didn't help nor did enabling CORS on IAppBuilder.

The web requests I expect are (based on the OWIN MCV example):

```
//Call to sign in which initiates the challenge
Request URL:http://localhost:55065/Account/SignIn
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:55065
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

//Call to perform the challenge.  Should redirect to MS login after this
Request 
URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[truncated]
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:104.42.72.20:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The web requests I'm actually seeing in my WebApi project are:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:13291/api/v1/tools/user/signin
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:13291
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL:http://localhost:13291/api/v1/tools/user/signin
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:13291
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[truncated]
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:104.210.48.14:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[truncated]
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:104.210.48.14:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Here's a summary of my set up followed by relevant code:

- Registered a new application through Azure AD with a Reply URL of http://localhost:13291 to match what I'm running locally.
- I use that same URL as the RedirectUri for OpenIdConnectionAuthenticationOptions
- I use the registered application's AppID as the CliendID for OpenIdConnectionAuthenticationOptions
- React is using JQuery $.post
- The only place CORS is enabled is off of the IAppBuilder in the OWIN startup class.

**Code excerpts**
I've removed namespace definitions and some class definitions for brevity.  The code below is from a new minimal example I created to reproduce the problem outside of the larger web application I'm working on.  The front end is just a simple JQuery call.  I'd like to provide access to the solution but it currently contains my AppSecret which I believe is required to even attempt to reproduce this.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static HttpConfiguration Register()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    return config;
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    //...
    //Obtain various application settings
    //...

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);  
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = appId,
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,  //http://localhost:13291
            TokenValidationParameters = ...,
            Notifications = ...,
            AuthenticationFailed = ...
        }

        app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
    }
}
```

**FooController.cs**

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/tools/user/signin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SignIn()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null || HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = "/"};
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication
                   .Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function signIn() {
            $.post("/api/v1/tools/user/signin", (r) => {
            }).fail((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="signIn" type="button" value="SignIn" onclick="signIn();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same problem with CORS, using web api 2 and angular 4, but the CORS triggered when I lost the cookie time expires. I'm trying to access to microsoft Graph API in order to request information. Here is the error: Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ee6a597e-7607-4ad5-99f7-efd71c4afb64&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%[removed]: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44300' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas
Check this out, it helped me with cross domain requests from angular on my web api

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that post but wasn't able to resolve it.  I think it's a configuration issue between WebApi and OWIN.  I _think_ the OWIN middleware is supposed to take care of CORS when making the authentication request and redirecting but that's not happening in my case.